# WebP and Accessibility - Alternative Text

Tags: accessibility, alt, webp

So we should all know that when using images in HTML it is good practice to provide alternative text... recently I have been looking at WebP... a new image format and the advantage is smaller file size, maintain quality and quicker websites.

However when I began looking into best practice for accessibility I couldn't find anything... no advice, no top tips on creating alternative text for screen readers for WebP images.

My code to serve alt text looks like this currently...

```
{% set optimizedImages = item.itemImage.one().imageVariantsThumb %}
{% set imageTitle = item.itemTitle %}
{% set imageClass = "br-100 h4 dib pa2" %}

<picture>
         {% if craft.imageOptimize.serverSupportsWebP() %}
             <source srcset="{{ optimizedImages.srcsetWebP() }}"
                             sizes="100vw"
                             type="image/webp"
                             class="{{ imageClass }}"
                             title="{{ item.itemTitle }}"
                             alt="{{ item.itemTitle }}" />
         {% endif %}
             <img src="{{ optimizedImages.src() }}"
                        srcset="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"
                        sizes="100vw"
                        class="{{ imageClass }}"
                        title="{{ item.itemTitle }}"
                        alt="{{ item.itemTitle }}" />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`source` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-source-element) does not have an `alt` attribute, unlike the `img` element, where you have correctly added that attribute.

On the `source` element, you could try adding the [`aria-label` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-label).

Answer (score 0):

> no top tips on creating alternative text for screen readers for WebP images

Because there is nothing about the image format which would affect how you write alternative text.

It is the same for any other `<img>` or `<picture>` element.

Comment: So it would be <source alt="text" /> ?

Comment: No. A picture element just provides alternative sources for the image element inside it. You put the `alt` attribute on the `<img>` inside it.

Comment: So I would remove alt text on the source and it will work?